# How can I set AllowEmptyStrings for all Code First Required strings?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I can decorate an individual string in a model with this attribute -

`[Required(AllowEmptyStrings= true)]`

How can I do this for all Required strings from OnModelCreating?

Note I do not want to turn validation off like this -

```
mDbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think the answer to this is that you can't.

In the FluentAPI you can use a custom convention that will apply across the entire context:

```
//All strings are required
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
    .Configure(p => p.IsRequired());

//All strings named "Foo" are required and have a maximum length
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == "Foo")
    .Configure(p => p.IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256));

//All strings with a "Required" attribute have a maximum length:
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
    .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes
                .Where(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(RequiredAttribute))
                .Any())
    .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(256));
```

The problem is that the Fluent API doesn't give access to an "AllowEmptyStrings" property. It has probably been designed with configuring the database in mind. And checking for empty strings is validation that would normally be done before the data gets to the database

Reference: [Custom Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj819164#introducing)

Comment: Thx. I could not find anything either iterating through the available modelBuilder API.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can subclass the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute`, and override the `IsValid()` method. 
As per the source: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RequiredAttribute.cs

Ideally you'd use a different attribute for "best practices" (and remove `[Required]`), but in my case I'm generating models with a designer, so I made the decision to expose the `[RequiredAttribute]` literally in the namespace, thus causing my models to use my own "Required" attribute instead of EF's. Works like a charm, globally.

While I agree with Colin above - this isn't "great practice" (by EF design), I wouldn't call it "bad practice" either. I'd probably call it "unsafe practice".
EF has a heavy hand, and I prefer to manage my database my own way, not theirs.
The main issue with this is going to be `<TKey>`'s which are of type `string`. Like the default `AspNetUsers` (etc). Hence unsafe.
If you can guarantee your code is properly used, it's a non-issue though.

such as..

> *(note: I chose not to override `IsValid`, as the below is far cleaner than an override)*

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RequiredAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute {
    public RequiredAttribute() : base() {
        AllowEmptyStrings = true;
    }
}
```

If I had a choice I'd probably improve on this using a <T> type check for strings specifically, but at that point you might as well replace `[Required]` everywhere with an appropriate item.
That's what I'll do in the long run.. Use a custom attribute in the designer upon the fields I specifically need it for. But as per your question, the answer above.